# Programmatically get reply / forward state via office-js?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I have an Outlook Office-JS addin that adds what is basically a third-party send via an addin command button.  In the background, this does some processing on the draft message then sends it via the Office365 / Graph send API: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/message_send

I've verified when I do send the message from the backend component of my app, I do see that the e.g. reply headers are set correctly, but apparently this isn't enough to set the parent message as replied / forwarded in Outlook.

Given that, I'd like to manually set the parent message as replied to / forwarded when sending.  From reading other posts it looks like the following attributes https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtaglastverbexecuted-canonical-property could help me do that.

However, I'm not sure how to identity a draft message on either the Office-JS side or via the Graph API as a reply / forwarded email, nor do I know how to get the parent message (original email replied to / forwarded)  handle or ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you cannot get the state of a draft or the parent ID with Office JS. What is your scenario for saving a message as a draft and then sending with Graph? We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: I'm basically implementing append-on-send to add tracking pixels to emails sent with our addin by picking up the draft from a backend app, inserting the tracking pixels and then sending it via the REST APIs.  Can you please add a link to the user-voice page?  Thanks!

Comment: @RafalBoni We have edited our answer to add the link to our user-voice page. Thanks.